# Getting error when using where() or filter() on Dataframe

Tags: python, boolean-expression, pyspark

I want to check if the value in the Dataframe Column `first_id` is in a python list of ids that I have, if it is then it should pass the filter.

```
first_id_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

other_ids = id_dataframe.where(ids["first_id"] in first_id_list).select("other_id")
```

I'm writing in python, `id_dataframe` is a PySpark Dataframe and `first_id_list` is a python list of integers.

The error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem in this expression : `ids["first_id"] in first_id_list`

`ids["first_id"]` is a Pyspark Column. `first_id_list` is a Python list.

`where()` Pyspark Dataframe method require a Boolean column to evaluate, but you give it a wrong python boolean expression.

You must use the Pyspark Column method `isin()` (documentation :https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin)

Answer :

```
other_ids = id_dataframe.where(ids["first_id"].isin(first_id_list)).select("other_id")
```

Now `ids["first_id"].isin(first_id_list)` is a DataFrame boolean expression returning a boolean column.

Comment: feel like an idiot, since this so obviously "isin()" the documentation... But it's working, thank you for taking the time to answer!